# Javascript Comparing String and Number

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, some of these are not coming out as I expected...In the console window I type:

```js
console.log( Number > String ); //returns false.
console.log( "A" > Number ); //returns false.
console.log( Number > "A" ); //returns true.
console.log( 1 > "A" ); //returns false.
console.log( "A" > 1 ); //returns false.
console.log( 1 == "A" ); //returns false.
```

Can somebody explain these two oddities?

Comment: `Number > String` coerces to `"function Number() { [native code] }" > "function String() { [native code] }"`, which is false because `N` comes before `S`, not after.

Comment: It just returns a possibility for you to do sorting, there is no oddity where you think you see it

Comment: Which two do you think are oddities?

Comment: Questioning started with me observing 1 > "A" , "A" > 1 and 1 == "A" all being false

Comment: And [here's the answer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) as to why that happens *(hint : conversion is different if the value is, or is not a string  )*

Comment: So it's three oddities, not two? What is the purpose of the first three examples?

Comment: "A" is coerced to NaN. Both `NaN > 1` and `1 > NaN` are false.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol—for the [*abstract relational comparison*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) algorithm, *ToPrimitive* is called with hint Number (steps 3 a and c), so `Number > String` becomes `NaN > NaN` (since they are both function objects) which is false.